# Finding number of arguments in argv?

Tags: c, arguments

So something simple like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int size = sizeof(argv);
    printf("%d", size);
}
```

If I pass it 5 arguments, it tells me there's 4 arguments. If I pass it 10 arguments, it tells me there's 4 arguments. Is something wrong here or is my compiler messed up?

Comment: `sizeof(argv)` is the size of a pointer, typically 4 or 8, happens to be 4 on your system. Perhaps you should just use the value in `argc`, since that's what it's there for.

Comment: The number of arguments is represented by _argc_ variable.

Comment: Thanks folks. Highly appreciated.

Comment: Try compiling with all warnings turned on, usually `-Wall`, it should warn you that sizeof on pointer of array function parameter will return size of `char **`. If you want to know how many arguments, thats what `argc` is for.

Comment: Moreover, `argc` is arguments+1 due to the executable in launch command.

Comment: The standard is ambigous it just says "program name" but doesn't say what exactly that means and leaves it up to the implementation, like all other arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
int size = sizeof(argv);
```

This does not give you the number of arguments in the `argv` array, it gives you the size of the `argv` variable in bytes. This is commonly four or eight for pointers at the time I'm answering this question and it's obviously four in your particular case.

If you want to know how many items are in `argv`, that's *exactly* what `argc` is for.

The `argc` integer holds the number of arguments, including the first one which usually represents the program being run. So, you can get the arguments with a loop like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("Argument #%d is %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running that with certain arguments show it in action:

```
pax$ ./testprog abc def 123 789
Argument #0 is ./testprog
Argument #1 is abc
Argument #2 is def
Argument #3 is 123
Argument #4 is 789
```

*Another* way, since it's mandated that `argv[argc]` must be the NULL pointer, is to bypass the count and check the values directly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (char **arg = argv; *arg != NULL; ++arg) {
        printf("Argument is %s\n", *arg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That has slightly different output because I'm not using a counter but the arguments are exactly the same:

```
pax$ ./testprog pax diablo
Argument is ./testprog
Argument is pax
Argument is diablo
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation from gcc [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html#Program-Arguments)

Quote:

> The value of the argc argument is the number of command line
>   arguments. The argv argument is a vector of C strings; its elements
>   are the individual command line argument strings. The file name of the
>   program being run is also included in the vector as the first element;
>   the value of argc counts this element. A null pointer always follows
>   the last element: argv[argc] is this null pointer.
>
> For the command ‘cat foo bar’, argc is 3 and argv has three elements,
>   "cat", "foo" and "bar".

`argc` is essentially there to know total count of commandline arguments passed in the command line. Even the executable name is listed in the command arguments (If you are wondering why - Look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315812/why-does-argv-include-the-program-name) (Advanced)).

So As a short answer, `argc - 1` will give you total number of arguments. It is a very common programming practice to check `argc` to confirm whether the minimum required number of arguments are passed or not.